# Offline speech recognition in Android virtual device

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-virtual-device, google-voice-search

I am developing an Android app which includes speech recognition.

Google Voice typing in my AVD works fine only when there is an internet connection. But I wanted it to work offline. I tried for offline speech recognition but I didn't find that option in any of the AVDs I have. So I just wanna know does any AVD have offline speech recognition option. If so, please specify the device.

Comment: Are you not able to install/download them via the AVD from the Android Voice Settings (Language & Input - Google Voice Typing)?

Comment: @brandall Yes. No option is available for that like "Offline speech Recognition"

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of Google 'Now'?

Comment: My AVD manager shows some image updates but they fail saying some error. As I am in my hostel, I don't know whether it is a problem with my college's firewall or with my installation or with google